# Verify the discrete log of ECDSA is in range

Tags: discrete-logarithm

Is it possible to verify the discrete log in elliptic curve is within range without uncovering it? I need to verify that $x$ is within $1$, $2^{64}$ for $xG=P$.

Answer (score 1):

If you give an attacker $G$ and $P := xG$ with $0<x<2^{64}$ then she can calculate a table with $2^{32}$ entries $yG$ for $0\le y<2^{32}$. Finding for any $0\le z<2^{32}$ the value $P-(z\cdot 2^{32}\cdot G)$ in the table yields $x = y + z\cdot 2^{32}$. Space complexity is $2^{32}$ entries and time complexity $\le\log_2(2^{32})\cdot 2^{32}$.

That's why user679128 uses a blinding scalar $b$.

Comment: Thanks for doing the complexity calculations, I made a mistake in my answer when I stated that finding x would reduce to the DLOG when the blinder is set to zero or exposed

Answer (score 0):

You can use a commitment styled rangeproof to show that your committed point is within the specified range.

An example of this is bulletproof.The point returned will be $P=xG+bH$ where $b$ is a blinding scalar.

You can either set b to be zero or you can reveal b along with the proof. The verifier will still not be able to know what $x$ is given that he cannot break the discrete log.

Edit:

Reading janes answer, we cannot set the blinder to zero or reveal because the space and time complexity to find $x$ reduces to finding a number between $0$ and $2^64$ , moreover the adversary only needs to calculate the lookup table once.

Note that this will also not be secure in the honest verifier model because that model only assumes that the verifier will follow the protocol, he could still leave and calculate the lookup table from the leaked information.

Comment: I read the bulletproof and it need the signer give a proof. So it is not possible to someone have a guess that the discrete in range (1,2^64) only from the P (public key) right? I’m insecure if there is away to know that.

Comment: @Zelleon I don’t quite understand what you are saying. If the range is (1,2^64) then an attacker will be able to compute it, but not guess correctly

Comment: @Zelleon Check our Dalek-cryptography/bulletproof , it does exactly what you need